# Android 12 - Room db encryption issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-2, android-12

Getting this error on Android 12 only when trying to access the Dao for the first time in the app. Works perfectly fine in Android versions below.

AppModule:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(): MyApplication = app

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePMDatabase(app: MyApplication): MyAppDatabase {
        val editable = SpannableStringBuilder(generateSymmetricKey("mykey").toString())
        val factory = SafeHelperFactory.fromUser(editable)
        return Room
                .databaseBuilder(app, MyAppDatabase::class.java, BuildConfig.DATABASE_NAME)
                .openHelperFactory(factory)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSettingsDao(database: MyAppDatabase): SettingsDao = database.settingsDao()


    private fun generateSymmetricKey(keyAlias: String): Key {

        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
        keyStore.load(null)
        if (!keyStore.containsAlias(keyAlias)) {
            val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore")
            val keyGenParameterSpec =
                    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                            keyAlias,
                            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                       .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                            .build()
            keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec)
            return keyGenerator.generateKey()
        }
        return keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, null)
    }
```

Room dependencies

```
//Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.3.0"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
```

Error says:
file is not a database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master; The detailed log is as below:

```
SQLiteCompiledSql.java in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile()
SQLiteCompiledSql.java line 91 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile()
SQLiteCompiledSql.java line 64 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>()
SQLiteProgram.java line 89 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.<init>()
SQLiteQuery.java line 48 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.<init>()
SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java line 60 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query()
SQLiteDatabase.java line 2012 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory()
SQLiteDatabase.java line 1898 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery()
SQLiteDatabase.java line 2647 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.keyDatabase()
SQLiteDatabase.java line 2577 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabaseInternal()
SQLiteDatabase.java line 1243 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()
SQLiteDatabase.java line 1318 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase()
SQLiteOpenHelper.java line 166 in net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()
Helper.java line 172 in com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase()
Helper.java line 82 in com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper.getWritableDatabase()
RoomDatabase.java line 622 in androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction()
RoomDatabase.java line 399 in androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction()
SettingsDao_Impl.java line 246 in mypackage.data.source.local.daos.SettingsDao_Impl.getSettingValue()
RequestInterceptor.kt line 65 in mypackage.data.source.remote.RequestInterceptor.intercept()
RealInterceptorChain.kt line 109 in okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed()
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Issue is definitely with the encryption using com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom (which is not maintained anymore, so can't blame the library)

I changed it to use

```
    implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.5.0@aar'
    implementation "androidx.sqlite:sqlite-ktx:2.1.0"
```

and the code to

```
val editable = SpannableStringBuilder(generateSymmetricKey("mykey").toString())
// val factory = SafeHelperFactory.fromUser(editable)
val passphrase: ByteArray = SQLiteDatabase.getBytes(editable.toString().toCharArray())
val factory = SupportFactory(passphrase, null, false)
```

Application runs the first time. After that I get the error again.

**NOTE**
**If I comment out setting the factory i.e. Room.openHelperFactory(factory), application works fine.**

Comment: can you please post your complete error from logcat, and your dao ?

Comment: unfortunately this is all I get.
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is not a database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master;

Comment: can you please post the method in the dao file which trigger this error ?

Comment: updated code in post

Comment: @sb_29 last thing please could you post the code of AppModule where you provide the `database` and `dao`

Comment: updated in the post

Comment: "Application runs the first time. After that I get the error again." -- the implication is that you are not providing the same passphrase when you try opening the database, compared to what you used when you created the database. I would start by getting rid of the `SpannableStringBuilder` (you don't need it). FWIW, [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.9/ToDoGen) demonstrates using Room and SQLCipher for Android with a generated encrypted key, though I am using `androidx.security` for the encryption.

Comment: I will have a look at your sample project and give that a go. It is funny because the same code works on Android versions below 12.